# Set units for layer dynamicly accoring to the dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to change the unit size for the last layer according to the dataset.
That is a abstraction of my code, but it's not working.

```
class cnn_model:
 num_classes = 1

 model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
 model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
 model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
 model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
 model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))


@staticmethod
def train_two():
 cnn_mod = cnn_model
 cnn_mod.num_classes = 2
 model = cnn_mod.model

@staticmethod
def train_three():
 cnn_mod = cnn_model
 cnn_mod.num_classes = 3
 model = cnn_mod.model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass number of classes as argument when you instantiate a new `CNNModel` class:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class CNNModel:

    def __init__(self, num_classes=2):
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        self.model.add(layers.Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax'))

cnnmodel = CNNModel(num_classes=3)
kerasmodel = cnnmodel.model
print(cnnmodel.num_classes) # 3
```

I would also suggest you to read [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) and [Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).